# Android.Views.InflateException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm testing a sample app and I get the runtime exception: `Android.Views.InflateException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>` on line

> SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

The problem is the button in `Main.axml`:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/playButton"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/playButton_size"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/playButton_size"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_play_circle_outline_dark_blue_48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

If I replace `@dimen/playButton_size` above with 64dp from `Resources\values-sw320dp\dimens.xml` the error is resolved. Why? here is the full dimens.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <dimen name="playButton_size">64dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Comment: Did you delete `obj` and `bin` folder, then rebuild this project? If it running normally. I test your code in my project, it could running normally, Could you provide a simple demo to re-produce this issue?

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I cloned it from here(https://github.com/jonashendrickx/rgrfm_xamarin) while looking for examples using media player for my own app. I'm not worried about fixing the code, I just was interested in why it didn't work until I edited the line.

Comment: I test it in my pc, this project could running normally, https://imgur.com/a/SSG9tb1, Do you used Hyper-V or HAXM to acclerate the emulatoer? Based on your error message and my test result, I think issue may related to the compiler is too late to compile

Comment: @LeonLu I use Hyper-V *but* strangely, when I disable hyper-v and restart to test on a mac and ios running in a hacked vmware image, the android virtual virtual machine still boots the android images which doesn't make any sense if Hyper-v is disabled. I don't know how.

Comment: Hyper-V was used to  acclerate the emulater, If you disable it, emulater could run it normally, I means that if the compiler cannot compile normally at the first time, you could delete `obj` and `bin` folder, then make the compiler build this project completely.

Comment: @leon I'll try it

Comment: Ok, waitting for your update.

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for the error message:

> Android.Views.InflateException: Timeout exceeded getting exception details

Is that it's trying to render something too large, or alternatively a parameter that it's trying to apply can't be compiled from resources which is a little harder to spot.

Delete obj, bin folders, perform a clean, and rebuild and attempt it again. That's usually the best option for a problem that seems a little transient.

also bear in mind that android does not perform any kind of optimization of images, it expects you to do this, so you'll also get inflate exceptions if it's trying to load an image that exceeds the available heap size assigned to the the application by the OS.